# How to parse an array from a certain spot?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

My java program takes in a line of inputs, for example:

```
q 1 1 K 2 2 B 3 3: 2 2 5 4
```

I want my program to read everything to the right of the colon. I converted it to an array, but I don't want to simply start the array at the index that's right after the colon i.e.

```
array[9]
```

because not all of my inputs will have 9 elements before the colon, some inputs may have more or less. Is there any way to parse the array starting with the element right after the colon, regardless of how many elements are before the colon?

Comment: how did you convert it into array? Please show your code so far.

Comment: do you expect a string of the numbers after the colon `:` or an array of strings consisting of the elements after the colon?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to remove the substring before : and then convert the new string to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get into regex, which could be difficult to read and write, a simple [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) would suffice if that's all you really need.